# why is my second function not being excecuted

Tags: python

My program doesn't enter the `searcholdvalue()` function.

**My code, Edit:**

```
filename = Date + 'counter.json'

if not os.path.isfile(filename):
    outfile = open(filename, "w")

counter_value = 1
with open(filename, 'a') as feedjson:
       json.dump('counter_value : ' + str(counter_value), feedjson)
       json.dump('timestamp : ' + time_now , feedjson)
       json.dump('\n', feedjson,)
       feedjson.write('\n')

def energy_consumption_per_hour():
    if counter_value == 1:     
        actual_time= time_now
        actual_val= counter_value
        old_time= datetime.today() - timedelta(hours=1)
        def search_old_value():
            json_data = json.load(open(filename).read())
            for i in json_data:
                if i['timestamp'] == old_time:
                    search_old_value = i['counter_value']
                    break
            old_value= search_old_value
            energy_consumption_per_hour= ((actual_val- old_value)/(actual_time-old_time))

test= energy_counsuption_per_hour
```

JSON file looks like this:

```
"counter_value : 20""timestamp : 2018-01-04 12:44:05""\n"
"counter_value : 10""timestamp : 2018-01-04 12:44:07""\n"
```

The Result should be `10kWh`.

**Question:** Why isn't my code entering the `searcholdvalue()` function?

Comment: Is that really how your code looks?

Comment: (1) That isn't valid JSON. (2) Please provide a [mcve] -- the shortest possible code *someone else can actually run to see your problem* (that is to say, your sample code should produce the exact same bug you're actually running about, not an error about needing to `import json`, and not doing nothing because its functions were never called).

Comment: Where do you call either of these functions? What has the JSON file got to do with anything? Neither of these functions return anything so how do you get any output at all? Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and edit your question to make it something that can be answered.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I created this data with JSON Command
I updated the code and i hope its now understandable

Comment: A bunch of separate `json.dump()` calls' results concatenated together does not a valid JSON file create.

Comment: Beyond that, I still don't see why you'd *expect* the code in `searcholdvalue` to be entered -- you aren't actually calling it anywhere. (I also don't see why you're defining it inside a nested scope rather than  defining it at top level and then *invoking* it where you need it).

Comment: ...so, if you want your "JSON" file to *actually* be JSON, your code writing it needs to be more like `json.dump({"counter_value": counter_value, "timestamp": time_now}, feedjson)` -- writing a single dictionary, not a series of separate strings.

Comment: I dont see any difference if i wrote the both at the same time in one commande or write them in 2 lines? Could you expleain me the advantages of your way used
Second question:
Do i need to write indent=4 to get every entry in new line or python will do that autoamatically which i dont think

Answer (score 0):

[Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!

The first of your problems is that you're not calling `searcholdvalue()` anywhere

Comment: Thank you for the answer. the function is called in this line  old_value= search_old_value

Answer (score 0):

Python is white space formatted since everything is indented under `if counter_value == 1` nothing is executed unless counter_value is 1.  In the code  provided it is never set before use. Therefore I expect none of it to execute. Then there is the problem where there is no code after searcholdvalue outside of the body of searcholdvalue, so there is nothing capable of calling it.

Comment: i didnt yrite it before because i dont want you to read and waste time for reading the whole code. 
i updated the code. Do you have a Clue yhere should i call the function

Comment: @AhmyOhlin On the line `old_value= search_old_value` currently it is outside the for loop but still inside the function search_old_value.  If that is supposed to be outside of the function try unindenting it more.

Answer (score 0):

Is it expected the remainder of the function is to be executed when counter_value != 1 you need to make a change there. Next there is a spelling mistake in the function name and variable energy_counsuption_per_hour
Also is it required to have searcholdvalue to be implemented as a nested variable? See [inner functions](https://realpython.com/blog/python/inner-functions-what-are-they-good-for/) for good reasons to inner functions

Comment: thank you for the adive.  by every new entry in json file i need to calculate the energy_consumption within last hour. this why i wrote the second function to find the old value in JSON file and to use it in the first function